# I have spring mvc and tiles. Now I need user control

Tags: java, spring, user-controls, tiles

I am not really femiliar with java web tchnologies.
I am using spring mvc with apache tiles. Now I desire to create a user control (user control like in asp.net).
For example, I am going to use many times in specific html pattern (like address chooser that uses cascading drop downs and ajax calls).

What is the best thecnology/framework that will allow me create user controls and will work good with spring mvc and tiles?

Comment: Spring MVC is really action-based, although you can create arbitrary JavaScript components with no problem. If you want a component-oriented environment you might be happier with JSF.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Isn't there any way to combine spring mvc with "user controls"? Can't I create "user control" and put in inside jsp that is one of my views? I can create JavaScript component but I must conect it to actual elements and server side operations. Can JSF work together with spring mvc?

Answer (score 0):

You can have something that helps you to reuse some code, but in the end it is nothing more like a (more or less intelligent) snippets. (Dave Newton already explaind in his comment, that jsp are action based and not component oriented)

It is called custom tags: `tag` or `tagx`.

And good example how to use `tagx` files and `jspx` files (the `x` is important) works together can be found in a spring roo project.

@See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalk.html -- may not so good example but it should be complete